# How to use #define in struct initialisation

Tags: c

I don't know if the title is clear enough, so here is what I want to do. I want to use a `#define` to define the size of array in a struct.

I'm doing this like this, but it don't want to work :

```
#ifndef DEF_MAIN
#define DEF_MAIN

#define TAILLE_TAB = 100;

typedef struct Personne Personne;
struct Personne
{
    char nom[TAILLE_TAB];
    char prenom[TAILLE_TAB];
    int age;
};

#endif
```

But I get an error.

If instead I put:

```
{
    char nom[100];
    char prenom[100];
    int age;
};
```

Then it works...
Why does the first solution doesn't work ? =(
Can't use a #define VAR on code on the same file ?

Comment: Whenever you get an error,Please post the **exact error message** as it will help us a lot

Comment: Ok, I'll do this from now :)

Comment: @SoJJu Please edit this question and add the error message you get. How can we help you resolve an error if you don't even tell us what the error is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, it's:

```
#define TAILLE_TAB 100
```

Comment: Thanks you. I'm feeling stupid.

And thanks to all Kevin that put -1 without telling my errors. Nice mentality. When someone need help in the street, you throw rock at him ?! -_-; You've never be needing help too I guess...

Comment: @SoJJu The downvotes (of which I'm not part) are probably against your (apparent) lack of research. This is basic syntax, and would be uncovered by a Google search in no time.

Comment: @SoJJu And because of your lack of effort. If you want help, give us enough information to help you. Not including error messages is something you just don't do.

Comment: I searched, but not with the right terms. Wasn't thinking that my syntax was bad... That's why i'm feeling stupid ^^
Anyway, downnote without comment and/or argument are just not constructives, and I prefer being stupid and making error like this than be like them :]

Thanks you ;)

Comment: Yes FUZxxl, Bill Lynch told me that in the first comment. I'll think to it in next posts :)

Comment: @SoJJu ,Bill Lynch did not even post a comment!

Comment: @CoolGuy Ha, yeah, that was you... xD
My god, I haven't drink I swear !

Comment: Well that was some easy reputation.

Comment: As you say. Just a little ashamed. Epic thread ^^
I think I just wrote a list of what you MUST NOT do when creating a thread :D